# Is there a way in JavaScript to reduce callstack size in recursive function calls?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is responsible to draw onto a canvas. The function does some heavy lifting and as i understand it, the variables of this heavy lifting are kept in memory since requestAnimationFrame() does not clear/reset the call stack.

A recent Firefox Update brought up this issue to me (resulting in > 10GB of RAM used within seconds). It worked in previous versions of Firefox and it works in Chrome so it might be a bug,. But nevertheless i want to know if there is a way to fix this myself or write better code.

Thanks in advance!

**Example code:**

```
"use strict";

class DrawUnit {
  constructor(canvas){
    this.canvas = canvas;

    window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        this.draw()
    });
  }

  draw(){
    let data = generateAndProcessData(); //heavy lifting happening here, old data stays in memory because the previously called draw() still has a reference to it right?

    let ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    //reset canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for(let d of data){
        //draw some line
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        this.draw()
    })
  }
}
```

setTimeout() delivers the same result, but i prefer to use requestAnimationFrame()

I think the problem and solution is related to the anonymous function in line 5 `this.draw()` but i was not able to find any solution by myself. If i don't use an anonymous function, i loose execution context, but i need that!

Comment: *"...as i understand it, the variables of this heavy lifting are kept in memory since requestAnimationFrame() does not clear/reset the call stack...."* That's incorrect. When your callback is called, the userland stack will be empty (only platform code on the stack), and when your callback returns, it will be empty again. `draw` doesn't look like it has any recursion. Obviously without knowing what `generateAndProcessData` does we don't know whether that's recursive.

Comment: Is `generateAndProcessData` based on timing? I mean, can you do all that (prepare the data) before actually requesting some output (in `requestAnimationFrame` callback)?

Comment: *"...old data stays in memory because the previously called draw() still has a reference to it right?"* No. If you create a function in `draw`, then *that* function might keep `data` alive, but `draw` itself won't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Firefox Debugger shows me that the Call stack has multiple entries of "draw()". https://imgur.com/a/nVBClYa

Comment: @CrazyFluffyPony - Then the code above isn't the full story. Again: `draw` never calls itself in the code in the question, so in the code in the question, it isn't recursive.

Comment: @raina77ow  generateAndProcessData() calls AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(new Uint8Array(255)) and then performs some smoothening and multiplications, nothing too fancy and for sure not recursive.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if you want to look at the complete (and WIP) code: https://javis.flaffipony.rocks/ load in any audio file (click bottom bar, left icon) and after a couple of seconds, debug the script javis_visualizer.js at draw() in line 492

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also realized i was missing a requestAnimationFrame call in the code of the question, sorry for that...

Comment: Maybe the anonymous arrow function on line 542 (when requesting the next animation frame) is keeping a closure of variables in the draw function. Maybe replacing it with `window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this))` would fix the issue.
Edit: lol I was writing this while T.J. posted the same thing as an answer.

Comment: (Weird, my comment disappeared.) That missing call makes all the difference, and explains the Firefox call stack (and possibly why you're having an issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`draw` isn't actually recursive. Firefox's call stack is showing you a *notional* call stack that includes asynchronous nesting for debugging purposes. The actual call stack is cleared when `draw` returns.

The closure you're creating to pass to `requestAnimationFrame` does, in theory, retain a reference to `data` indirectly through the lexical environment object it closes over. Browsers may or may not be able to optimize that link away (I know that V8, the JavaScript engine in Chrome and others, used to be fairly aggressive about closure optimization but backed off it a bit — **not** entirely — because of the execution time impact it had).

The good news is that we can avoid the closure entirely by using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));
```

`bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to whatever `bind`'s first argument is. It doesn't creaet a closure in the current context.

So now there's no closure created during the call to `draw`, so nothing retains `data` from previous calls (in the absense of optimization).

---

The callback you give `requestAnimationFrame` should never be doing heavy lifting, though. It's required to do its work **very** quickly. (Browsers will complain at you if the `rAF` callback takes more than a couple of milliseconds.)

If the "heavy lifting" is significant in terms of CPU time, you might want to offload it to a [web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) if possible and have it post the final data to the main thread ([`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage)) for rendering to the DOM. Code in the main thread processing the `message` event would then render it to the DOM to be painted by the browser when it next paints.

Comment: thx for the notional stack hint

the "bind" solution actually seems to increase the performance a tiny little bit, in terms of RAM getting filled up slower, but still within seconds.

i will see what i can do with WebWorkers, but i see no way around to do the processing just in time. Audio is changing, so if i want high FPS i need to process often and just in time.
But yes, i totally understand that reqestAnimationFrame is not meant to do heavy lifting and be fast. I will give it a try!